# wordpress check html class with php or jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to check the class of the html (there are posts and every category got a own class for background color) and then set the background.
I wanted to to it with jQuery but it doesn't work because the first one is true so all get the same background.

**My php code:**

```
<div class="grid" >
<?php
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post' );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post() ; ?>
    <div class="post grid-item <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name; }  ?>" style='background:  url("<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { the_post_thumbnail_url(); }  ?>"); background-color:<?php  ?>' >
      <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();
?>
</div>
```

**my jQuery code that doesn't work**

```
//post background
var back_engagement = jQuery('.grid div').hasClass('engagement');
var back_unternehmen =  jQuery('.grid div').hasClass('unternehmen');
var back_forum = jQuery('.grid div').hasClass('forum');

if (back_engagement){
  jQuery('.grid-item').css({"backgroundColor": "#959595"});
}
else if (back_unternehmen) {
  jQuery('.grid-item').css({"backgroundColor": "#96A306"});
}
else if (back_forum) {
  jQuery('.grid-item').css({"backgroundColor": "#215270"});
}
```

For me it doesn't mater if the solution is with php or jQuery

Comment: How about just defining those classes in css? Or am I missing some next level stuff?

Comment: check jquery hasClass here is link : https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the CSS property based on simple selector.

```
jQuery('.grid div.engagement').css({"backgroundColor": "#959595"});
jQuery('.grid div.unternehmen').css({"backgroundColor": "#96A306"});
jQuery('.grid div.forum').css({"backgroundColor": "#215270"});
```

---

However I would recommend you to set them using classes in CSS

```
.engagement{ background-color: #959595;}
```

Comment: `css` is being applied for `grid-item` element... Which is child of `grid`

Comment: @RayonDabre, If you look closely `.grid div` and `grid-item` are same element as there is only 1 div

Comment: he he! You are right! But still its better to go with the `class-selector` than `element-selector`(`.grid-item`)

Comment: thanks for the help. I am so dumb just realised that there aren't spaces between the classes when there are two categories